# How do I use multiple overloads to get different answers based on the amount of numbers passed in?

Tags: c++

Write a function `GetVolume()` with 3 overloads. If one value is passed in, find the volume of a sphere with that value being its radius. If two values are passed in, find the volume of a cylinder with those values being its radius and height. If three values are passed in, find the volume of a box with the three values being its length, width, and height.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double PI = 3.14;
double GetVolume(double r)
{
    cout << "Sphere's volume is: ";
    return ((4 * PI * pow (r , 3.0))/3);
}

double GetVolume(double r, double h)
{
    cout << "Cylinder's volume is: ";
    return (PI * pow (r, 2) * h);
}

double GetVolume(double l, double h, double w)
{
    cout << "Box's volume is: ";
    return (w * l * h);
}

int main()
{

    double num = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;
        double ans1, ans2, ans3;

        cout << "Please enter 1, 2, or 3 numbers depending on whether you want the volume of a sphere, cylinder, or a box." << endl;

        cin >> num1, num2, num3;

        ans1 = GetVolume(num1);
        ans2 = GetVolume(num1, num2);
        ans3 = GetVolume(num1, num2, num3);

        cout << ans1 << ans2 << ans3 << endl;

        system("pause");


    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why I cannot use my `getvolume` function to show three different results based on the numbers inserted in at the `cin`, I've attached at the top the question that I have to answer as to its part three of the five-part assignment. Sorry if this isn't enough information, I will try to provide more as best as I can.

Comment: Your code sample's a bit long, you should pare `main()` down to a [mcve].

Comment: Outputting strings in a function that is supposed to calculate something is not a good idea. This output should be done at the output stage of your program. Otherwise you will get undesired text output when calculating.

Comment: `math.h` already includes a definition of PI. You should use the c++ headers instead of the old c headers, although that is a point of contention. In any case you may need to `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before including math.h before you can use the `M_PI` define, defined as `3.14159265358979323846`

Comment: `GetVolume` should not print that title. or rename it `PrintVolume` (but then also print the volume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can declare class and overload `GetVolume` function like below

```
double PI = 3.14;

class calculateVolume {
    public:
    double GetVolume(double r)
    {
        cout << "Sphere's volume is: ";
        return ((4 * PI * pow (r , 3.0))/3);
    }

    double GetVolume(double r, double h)
    {
        cout << "Cylinder's volume is: ";
        return (PI * pow (r, 2) * h);
    }

    double GetVolume(double l, double h, double w)
    {
        cout << "Box's volume is: ";
        return (w * l * h);
    }
}

int main() {
    calculateVolume volObject;
    cout<<volObject.GetVolume(5);
    return 0;
}
```

above code will give output `Sphere's volume is: 523.333`

It is just working snippet you can adjust code according to your need

Comment: You don't need a class for that. You can make those functions static. The correct approach would be to have a class body with a purely virtual function GetVolume, which is then overloaded in derrived classes Sphere, Box and Cylinder. Outputting a string in those functions deminishes their flexibility, as say if you want to add the volume of a box to the volume of a cylinder, you would get random, unwanted text outputs. This is not good style, neither does it solve the actual problem of figuring out how many numbers have been entered.

Comment: @FalcoGer I don't think actual problem was to count  how many numbers have been entered. Problem was how to get output based on number of inputs? `The correct approach would be to have a class body with a purely virtual function GetVolume` then you need to create `three` virtual function in base class. `which is then overloaded in derrived classes Sphere, Box and Cylinder` you need to override function in derived classes and not overload

Comment: OP already has working overload functions. Putting them in a class is useless. OP has several "typo" in code making unexpected output.

Comment: @AviatorX no. the function getVolume would not take parameters, but instead operate on the instance of the body, which has it's radius/height, whatever else set.

Comment: @FalcoGer provided solution(mine) might not be perfect, so can you provide code snippet for your solution?

Comment: @AviatorX it is not the answer to the question. I will provide a link.

Comment: @FalcoGer Thanks for link, but problem is still there, because based on number of inputs you need to decide which object should be created first and then call `getVolume()`. e.g. if current number of arguments are `2` and user might enter `one` more argument or might not, so which object will you create? will it be `cylinder` or `box`?

Comment: @AviatorX which is why I said it is not a solution. And neither is your answer. What I meant was that if you want to use classes, then you should make actual objects, not an assortment of functions. besides that his original code works well, in regards to overloading anyway. the problem is detecting the number of inputs. Personally I'd have gone with a menu where the user selects what object to create before all of this. or maybe enter a string and split it by whitespace and then check how many elements there are and go from there. But I suppose there is some cin stream magic I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

You are only reading one number from standard input in this line

```
cin >> num1, num2, num3;
```

The commas here are `operator,`, which evaluates multiple expressions and discards all but the last. If you want to read multiple numbers, you need to chain `>>`

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```

However it looks like you want to know how many numbers were entered, which you can test by looking at the value returned by `operator>>`.

```
if (!(cin >> num1)) {
    cout << "no numbers entered";
} else if (!(cin >> num2)) {
    cout << GetVolume(num1);
} else if (!(cin >> num3)) {
    cout << GetVolume(num1, num2);
} else {
    cout << GetVolume(num1, num2, num3);
}
```

Comment: I can not seem to find `operator,` in http://www.cppreference.com or http://www.cplusplus.com. This operator seems to make no sense if all it does is just take the last value provided and throw away the rest. If you just wanted to use the last value, then why bother writing out the others?

Comment: @FalcoGer because an expression can change state as well as have a value. For instance `cin >> num1, num1` modifies `num1` and returns the value read. It's in the section [other operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) in cppreference

Comment: I have found the reference here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator. I have read it but it makes no sense still. all those expressions in the example can and should be on their own lines.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about the comma operator in c++.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Basically in the line,

```
num = GetVolume(num1), GetVolume(num1,num2), GetVolume(num1, num2, num3);
```

`GetVolume(num1)` gets evaluated. The result then gets discarded.

Then `GetVolume(num1,num2)` is evaluated. The result, discarded

Finally `GetVolume(num1, num2, num3)` gets evaluated, and its results is returned by the (Expr, Expr, Expr) on the RHS of `operator =`.

This returned value is then assigned to `num`. Which is why you only see one answer.

Similarly, your `cin >> num1, num2, num3;` Will only take one input i.e. num3.

Possible Fix

```cpp
int ans1, ans2, ans3;
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
ans1 = GetVolume(num1);
ans2 = GetVolume(num1, num2);
ans3 = GetVolume(num1, num2, num3);
```

#### Other Issues

1. You return a type `double` from your functions but store them in int. This is had significant precision loss. I believe you wanted to store a double instead.
2. Your `cout` and following code seem incoherent. Perhaps you wish you take a single input first. Test whether it is 1,2 or 3. Then act accordingly.

Comment: Exactly that, I want code to test how many numbers are inserted then act accordingly, also when I put any number in it runs through all three. showing my all my couts together.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703623/4944425) by [Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610810/caleth), if OP's issue (apart from the comma operator) is how to select a particular function based on how many numbers the user inputs, we may read an entire line from the input stream with `std::getline` and then, using a `std::stringstream`, extract a number at a time.

```
using std::cout;
cout << "Please enter 1, 2, or 3 numbers depending on whether you want"
        "the volume of a sphere, cylinder, or a box.\n";

std::string line;
while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) )
{
    if (line.empty())
        continue;

    std::istringstream ss {line};
    double num_1, num_2, num_3;
    if ( !(ss >> num_1) )
    {
        cout << "No number in input.\n";
        continue;
    }
    else if ( !(ss >> num_2) )
    {
        cout << "Sphere's volume is: " << GetVolume(num_1) << '\n';  
    }
    else if ( !(ss >> num_3) )
    {
        cout << "Cylinder's volume is: " << GetVolume(num_1, num_2) << '\n';  
    }
    else  // Other numbers in the line will be ignored.
    {
        cout <<  "Box's volume is: " << GetVolume(num_1, num_2, num_3) << '\n';  
    }
}
```

Live example [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8vTZWwB9fWJjC2an).